# Remove Inverted commas for only part of Batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, mkdir, icacls

I have created a batch file for a client to create a project directory

I have to add quotation marks when creating the root folder for wexample "A001 test project" This then created all the directories as i want.

When it comes to the ICACLS, it fails as it doesnt need the "" around the %dname%

How can i remove the quotations just for this part so that the ICACLS can work.

Batch file code below;

```html
color 9f
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO Directory Creator Tool
ECHO.
ECHO Any errors please report to Me
ECHO.

ECHO Type below the name of the new project 
ECHO.
ECHO.

ECHO PLEASE REMEMBER TO ADD COMMAS "BEFORE AND AFTER THE PROJECT NAME"
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Example... Enter Project Name?  "A001, Test Project"

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.


set /p dname= Enter Project Name?

mkdir P:\%dname%

mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Authorities
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Authorities\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Drainage
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Drainage\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Layout-Masterplan
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Layout-Masterplan\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"OS Data"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"OS Data"\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Planning
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Planning\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"Topo Survey"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"Topo Survey"\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Utilities
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\Utilities\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"Working Dwgs"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\"Base Information"\"Working Dwgs"\SuperSeded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\Correspondance
mkdir P:\%dname%\Communications\Correspondance\"Emailed Sketches"

mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings\"Base Xrefs"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings\"Base Xrefs"\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings\"Digital Copies"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings\"Digital Copies"\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\"Micro Drainage"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\"Micro Drainage"\Superseded
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\"Micro Drainage"\"Working Input-Output Files"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\PDS
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\PDS\"Working Input-Output Files"
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Reports
mkdir P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Reports\Superseded

mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\"CDM,H&S"
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Contract
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Financial
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Programme
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Proposal
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\QM
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Financial\"Cost Tracking"
mkdir P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\Financial\Invoices


xcopy P:\Templates\"BLANK Designers Risk Assessment DRA 01.docx" P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\"CDM,H&S"\
xcopy P:\Templates\"BLANK Designers Risk Assessment DRA 02.docx" P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\"CDM,H&S"\
xcopy P:\Templates\"BLANK Site Risk Assessment  Method Statement.docx" P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\"CDM,H&S"\

xcopy P:\Templates\"QM Form 904 Project Issue Register v2.docx" P:\%dname%\"Project Management"\QM

set /p dname= Enter Project Name?

ICACLS "P:\%dname%"  /inheritance:r

ICACLS "P:\%dname%" /grant:r JPITS05\Admin:(OI)(CI)(F)
ICACLS "P:\%dname%" /grant:r ALPCE:(OI)(CI)(F)
ICACLS "P:\%dname%" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(R)

icacls "P:\%dname%\Communications\Base Information" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Communications\Correspondance" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Drawings" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Micro Drainage" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Deliverables\PDS" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Deliverables\Reports" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\CDM,H&S" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\Contract" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\Financial" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\Programme" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\Proposal" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\QM" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)
icacls "P:\%dname%\Project Management\Financial\Invoices" /grant:r ALPCEusers:(OI)(CI)(F)

ECHO Complete
Pause
exit
```

Comment: Use a single set of quotes to enclose _the whole path_, like in `mkdir "P:\%dname%\Communications\Base Information\OS Data"`

Comment: Do not assign quotes to the variable when asking for the project name.  Just use quotes around your variable when it is needed for the command.

Comment: @Aacini YOU ARE A LIFESAVER         I knew it would be something i overlooked.. thank you

Comment: `When it comes to the ICACLS, it fails as it doesnt need the "" around the %dname%` - so why are you intentionally putting them in?

Comment: @Magoo im not intentionally putting them in.. if i dont put them in at the enter name it creates muliple folders... *Aacini resolved fore me now

Comment: As I said in my previous comment.  Use quotes with your variables when they are needed to execute a command. Best practice is to not assign quotes to your variables. `mkdir "P:\%dname%"`